# How to clone a NodeJS stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chunks, node-streams

I need to somehow clone a `readstream` in nodeJS.
That is if I have a `readStream` I need two copies of it stream1, stream2. Where I can read both the streams `stream1` and `stream2` individually.
How can I do that cause as far as I know you cant readily copy a stream also even If I try to pipe original `readStream` to `stream1`, `stream2` I cant consume each of them individually

Comment: check node js docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-stream-clone

Comment: What is your specific use case?  You can pipe to multiple places, but flow control issues will exist no matter what.

Comment: I need to check the encoding of data in readSteam. I am doing it using the detect-character-encoding module. But it requires me to read the chunks from the readStream to know its encoding, If I try to read the chunks I will lose data(chunks) that were required later in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this docs in npmjs package docs

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ReadableStreamClone = require("readable-stream-clone");

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');

const readStream1 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);
const readStream2 = new ReadableStreamClone(readStream);

const writeStream1 = fs.createWriteStream('sample1.txt');
const writeStream2 = fs.createWriteStream('sample2.txt');

readStream1.pipe(writeStream1)
readStream2.pipe(writeStream2)
```

try those line of code may be help you

Comment: `readable-stream-clone` has a memory leak (https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues/202#issuecomment-620626415). Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloneable-readable