# can't read data in stream after sending it to a different method

Tags: node.js

I am creating a readable stream correctly, however, after uploading that stream it looses the data within the stream

```js
const readable: Readable = await createCsv(csv)

console.log('step 1', readable.read()) // <---- the data is there
// uploadfile csv to FTP server
await this.ftp.uploadCSV(readable, pathway)
console.log('step 2', readable.read()) // <---- the data is not there

// return csv file to Front End
// FIXME: this shouldn't be done again
const r2: Readable = await createCsv(csv) // <--- have to create readable again to send back data

return { readable: r2 }
```

The issue is the same if `this.ftp.uploadCSV()` returns back the stream to be returned later in the function. So the question is how can I send the readable stream to another method of a class and return that same readable data without having to generate another stream, like in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uploadCSV` method consumes the data from the `readable` stream, causing it to become empty. To avoid this, you should clone the stream. There are multiple questions about stream cloning on Stack Overflow, one example of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041484/how-to-clone-a-nodejs-stream)